# openldap data files, what do they look like

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap

from my slapd.conf file, i see where my data is stored. when I look into that data directory i see two kinds of files, one type are `.bdb` files which appear to be the data files as that is the extension defined in the config file. But, I also have a bunch of log files, which appear to be binary when I try to read them in vi. I'm not sure if they are supposed to be there or if this is an oversight by someone previous to me. If I want to restore from an .ldif file, am I loosing anything by deleting all the log files? do I just need to delete the bdb files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are Berkeley DB files.

On Ubuntu 10.04, for example, you can install the `db4.7-util` package and get some information using the various `db4.7_*` utils (e.g. `db4.7_dump` or `db4.7_stat`). This being said, the structure of the database really depends on how OpenLDAP is coded (it's an internal format, so it's not particularly useful unless you really want to dig into it).

If you want to restore from an LDIF file, use LDAP clients or OpenLDAP commands such as `ldapadd`.